# iPhone app that reads out text messages

Tags: ios, iphone, sms

I needed to know if there exists some third party app for iPhone that reads out the newly received SMS to the user, like some app for drivers so that they can listen to the SMS without getting their hands on the mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask Siri to read new incoming text messages.

Comment: Yes I am aware of Siri, but is there any other third party app that provides this functionality?